# Use API v2 to work with Customer Group Prices

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

We are using a tool to integrate our financial software with Magento.

Does anyone know a way to write and read the Customer Group Prices with API v2?

Each customer has a different agreed price for products in Dynamics GP and we need to match this price in Magento.

This way, when a Customer logs into the Magento site, their agreed price will be displayed in all simple products.